# Optimize query: select followings' posts

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a simple social media with a follow system like Twitter, etc.

I have the tables

```
tb_follow
    id 
    account1_id 
    account2_id

tb_post 
    id 
    account_id 
    created_at 
    message
```

I have this query to select the most recent posts by users I'm following.

```
SELECT p.message
FROM tb_post as p
JOIN tb_follow as f
ON f.account1_id = 123 and f.account2_id = p.account_id 
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC, p.id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Can this query be optimized somehow?

And what columns should I index?

Comment: The criterion `f.account1_id = 123` might belong in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: try this question at [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks fine and whether you have the condition in join on clause or where is same since you are performing a `inner join`. You should have index created on the column `f.account2_id` and `p.account_id` since those two are involved in join condition `f.account2_id = p.account_id` as well have index on `f.account1_id` since that's included in filter `f.account1_id = 123`

```
SELECT p.message
FROM tb_post as p
JOIN tb_follow as f
ON f.account1_id = 123 and f.account2_id = p.account_id 
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC, p.id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: What about the `created_at` column? Any use indexing it?

Comment: @tumber033, yes you should index that column as well since you are using it in `order by`. You should use a indexed column in order by else it will result in file sort which will hurt the performance.